# Increase a battery Ah rating

Tags: batteries

How do I increase the Ah rating of a battery?  Will connecting two batteries in parallel increase the overall AH rating?

Answer (score 3):

1 - You can't.

2 - Yes; if you put two batteries in parallel, the combination will have twice the A-hr capacity of a single battery. (Actually, it will be a little bit more, since each battery will only have to provide 1/2 the current as it does when by itself, and this is a good thing.) HOWEVER. When you first connect the two batteries in parallel, you MUST put a resistor between them and let them equalize. Then short the two batteries and then remove the resistor. When you start, one will inevitably have a higher output voltage than the other, and the weaker battery will look like a short circuit to the stronger. With high-current capacity batteries, this can provide quite a spark if you just short them.

Answer (score 3):

You can't increase the overall Ah rating of a battery, but in theory the Ah rating of two batteries in parallel will sum (e.g. two 1000mAh batteries in parallel = 2000mAh).

In practice connecting two batteries in parallel is slightly tricky.  First of all you must make sure that you use two batteries with:

1. The same Ah rating
2. Identical battery specification
3. Same state of health

The reason for (1) is that connecting batteries with different Ah ratings will result in the battery with the lowest Ah rating discharging first, and the discharged battery will then draw current from the other.  In some cases, depending on the battery type, this could cause failure of a battery.

The reason for (2) is that batteries with different internal resistance ratings (for example) will result in an unbalanced share of the current delivery, causing the same situation as in (1).

And the reason for (3) is simply that a well used battery tends to have a reduced practical Ah rating and causes the same situation as in (1).

All things considered, connecting batteries in parallel for the long term is a tricky matter.  You really need to do it with the help of a power management system.